# Field Calculator in QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm trying to add a new field to an existing shapefile and filling it afterwards. I started doing this with the field calculator but as it involves many consecutive steps I thought it might be better to do it with the Python console.

As I never used the Python console before my code below is based on this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgvdgjyY03s

```
# define path to shape-file to work with
uri = 'D:/myfilepath/Windzonen_Deutschland.shp'

#adds layer to project
layer = QgsVectorLayer(fn, 'Windzonen_Deutschland_test', 'ogr')
pv = layer.dataProvider()

# create Field
pv.addAttributes([QgsField('Windzonen', QVariant.Int)])

layer.updateFields()

# create expressions
expression1 = QgsExpression('''case when "NAME_0"='Germany' then '1' end''')

# excute expressions for created fields
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f['Windzonen'] = expression1.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

If I run the code from the console as a block I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\core\additions\edit.py", line 38, in __enter__
    assert self.layer.startEditing()
AssertionError
```

If I run in line by line I get the following error for this line of code `pv.addAttributes([QgsField('Windzonen', QVariant.Int)])`:

```
False
```

I use QGIS 3.10.5.A Coruna

What am I doing wrong? I tried to add `layer.startEditing()` to my code but I did not solve the poblem and I think because of `with edit(layer)` this should not be necessary...

Any hints or links?

Comment: Can we talk about the presumption "it involves many consecutive steps" - maybe you could explain a bit, what you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: If you load the shapefile into QGIS Desktop, `D:/myfilepath/Windzonen_Deutschland.shp`, are you sure you can turn on edit mode?

Comment: @Erik: The new field "Windzonen" will receive vaues between 1 and 4 based on a national table with rules for that. In the example code i only added the first rule which sets all fields to the value 1. This exampley code did not work so I did not implement the ramaining rules. The result will look like this map: https://www.google.com/search?q=windzonen&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk00O6sDhfX3SUsgqhVn-NP7CAKRArg:1595255971499&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN2obMh9zqAhXNk4sKHfZ1AqYQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1280&bih=703&dpr=2#imgrc=wHq1Hemz9zNq5M.

Comment: I fail to see why this is an issue you need to use Python (or the field calculator) on.

Comment: @ etrimaille: This is my first try with QGIS and python. In the example video it worked like this, so I don't know why it doesn't work in my case. Do you have a suggestion how else I could edit the shp-file? after running this line `layer = QgsVectorLayer(fn, 'Windzonen_Deutschland_test', 'ogr')` the layer does not appear in my project. Should it?

Comment: @Erik The structure of the shape file is based on the smallest administrative units of germany. there are hundreds of them. I don't want to assign the values from 1 to 4 by hand to each of them.

Comment: You could use `add raster values to features` - true, you'd need to have a raster with 1 - 4 as values, not the usual Windzonen-maps I know of, but that can be created.

Comment: @Erik The official rules for this map don't have any coordinate information, they include names or IDs of administrative units: https://www.dibt.de/fileadmin/dibt-website/Dokumente/Referat/P5/Technische_Bestimmungen/Windzonen_Formular_nach_Verwaltungsgrenzen.xlsx

Comment: With `layer = QgsVectorLayer(fn, 'Windzonen_Deutschland_test', 'ogr')` changed to `layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Windzonen_Deutschland_test', 'ogr')` the field is added when I try.

Comment: @BERA Thank you! This solved part of the problem. I didn't realize that I renamed the path... Also for some reason I could not run the commented code with ending *.py. I removed the comments and runned it by copy-pasting it to the Python-console without saving it to a file. I don't get why I had to do this but now everything works.